# How to remove footer default text in joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

Ive been looking for settings in joomla to remove the default footer text but i cant find it.

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove it? im using the latest joomla.

Comment: Both answers are referring to the module(s) that are published in (what is normally, but not necessarily) called the "footer" position.  Go to http://docs.joomla.org/Finding_module_positions_on_any_given_page to see how to determine what the module position is that this text is appearing in, then go to your module manager and unpublishe that module (whatever it, or it's position) might be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the template you're using. With some template, there will be an options in the template parameters. Else if you open the **Footer** module in the Module Manager, you will see a text area with the content for the footer there

Comment: And is there an option in the Template parameters?

Comment: In which case, please contact the developer of your Template. If it's not a template option or part of the footer module, they have most likely hard coded it in

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the footer entirely, go to Extensions > Module Manager and unpublish the footer module.

Other places where can look for options to make changes are these. If you find code related to footers in these files, you can either "comment it out" or remove it:

/includes/footer.php file.

index.php file for your active template

Comment: see the footer.php in your joomla files or index.php in your theme.